# Calculating percentual of the elements of an array

Tags: c, arrays, printf, scanf, percentage

I have to read 10 integers, calculate the 90% of every value, print them in inverted order and at last print the mid value of the various values I've obtained.

But it doesn't work, it prints only zeros. Another thing is that after I've inputted the 10 values it still requires another input to start printing. I'm new to C, so I probably made a stupid mistake...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int n = 10;           //number of numbers
    float array[10];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {                 
        scanf("%d \n", &array[i] ) ;   //read the keyboard input and memorize it in the array
    }

    for( int i = 9; i > -1 ; i-- ) {
        array[i] = array[i]*90.0/100.0;        //calculate the 90% of every value 
        printf("%f \n", array[i]);         //prints the values in opposite order
    }

    float s = 0;                         
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        s = s+array[i];                    //add up all the values
    }

    float m =s/n;                          //calculate the mid value
    printf("%f \n",m);                     //prints it
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 90/100 is integer arithmetic, which results in 0.  Use 90.0/100.0

Comment: This _is not_ C++ code.  Did you mean to use the `C` tag?  If you want a C++ answer, the idiomatic way will be much more concise.  Also, you're going past the bounds of your `array`.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: should not be a problem since left to right evaluation of expression (float*90/100 remains float)...

Comment: i've made the array of 10 elements instead of 9 and i've transformed 90 and 100 in 90.0 and 100.0, still doesn't work though

Comment: @ninilo1: maybe `scanf` with `%d` doesn't work with `float` arguments (but I don't really know these C functions). Try using `%f` with scanf, and enter the integers at float like 4.0.

Comment: Do you want a `C` or `C++` answer?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Even if the array values were `int`s, `array[i]` is multiplied by 90 first, so integer division by 100 would still produce non-zero values: A C++ expression `50*90/100` yields the value `45`.

Comment: @OldProgrammer `90/100` is integer arithmetic, but that is not what was coded. Original code `float array[10]; ... array[i]*90/100` would perform a `(float*int)*int` resulting in `float` arithmetic all the way through.  Suggest comment deletion or retraction.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your problem:

```
scanf("%d \n", &array[i] ) ;   //read the keyboard input and memorize it in the array
```

The `array` elements are of type `float`, and you're told `scanf` to read an integer. Undefined behavior there. Try this:

```
scanf("%f \n", &array[i] ) ;   //read the keyboard input and memorize it in the array
```

Comment: @ninilo1: I don't think it was your only one, but have fun finding the rest. 8v)

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer is written for the original question's code.

---

Using a compiler that has decent diagnostic messages will help you out a lot in learning C++. The diagnostics produced by clang for your program highlight several issues, including the core issue giving you problems.

```
main.cpp:3:2: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
 main ()
 ^~~~
```

This occurs because function declarations must include a return type. For `main` it should be `int`, so you should write `int main()`.

```
main.cpp:12:19: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'float *' [-Wformat]
   scanf("%d \n", &array[i] ) ;   //read the keyboard input and memorize it in the array
          ~~      ^~~~~~~~~
          %f
```

Your array is an array of floats, yet you tell `scanf` to read integers ("%d" means `int`, "%f" means `float`). This will result in undefined behavior and is the likely cause of the strange behavior you describe (printing zeros instead of the expected values).

Since your assignment involves an array of integers you should probably change your array to use `int` instead of `float`. If you make that change then you'll need to change the `printf` format string to indicate `int`s instead of `float` as well.

Also you're confused on the size of the array. You've declared the array to hold 9 values when you in fact want ten. Presumably the thing that confused you is that the index to access the nth element is `n-1`, so to access the tenth element you write `array[9]`. This applies when accessing the elements, not when declaring the array. To declare an array of ten elements you say `int array[10];`. In your case you have a variable `n` which is used to iterate through the array; It's correct and good practice to use the same variable in both the loop and in declaring the array, as the following code snippet demonstrages:

```
const int n = 10;
int array[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
```

Since your code attempts to read a tenth value into an array of nine elements, the program again exhibits undefined behavior.

```
main.cpp:28:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'system'
     system("PAUSE");
     ^
```

You haven't included the right header for the `system()` function. You should `#include <stdlib.h>` (or in what's considered good practice for C++ you should `#include <cstdlib>` and explicitly qualify `system` as `std::system("PAUSE")`.

---

Once you fix these problems your program seems to work fine.

Comment: @ninilo1 clang is available for free and works well on Linux, BSD, and OS X. It doesn't support Windows very well yet. You can try it online at sites like http://rextester.com/runcode (select "C++(clang)"). VC++ unfortunately doesn't have such useful diagnostics and is very permissive of incorrect code. If you want to install a compiler with good diagnostics on Windows then you should probably go with the latest available version of gcc.

Answer (score 0):

OP's first problem, mis-matched format specifier in scanf() is well address by @bames53 and @Fred Larson.

```
float array[10];
...
// bad scanf("%d \n", &array[i] )
scanf("%f", &array[i]);
```

Answer to OP's 2nd problem follows:

> "Another thing is that after I've inputted the 10 values it still requires another input to start printing."

Concerning `scanf("%d \n",...`: the `' '` and `'\n'` do the same thing and likely not really what you want.  These require you to enter non-whitespace data after the number before `scanf()` returns.  Suggest:

```
scanf("%f", &array[i]);
// or
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
sscanf(buf, "%f", &array[i]);
```